# Iteratively pass elements of array to mapReduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

I'm trying to pass elements of a keywords array to my mapper function. The goal of this is to count the number of documents a keyword occurs in. I'm getting an error saying that the words array is not defined in the mapper function. When I have the mapper function emit(words[i],1), it doesn't know what words[i] is. How can I deal with this issue? Here is my code

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('hw4') //this is the database I'm working with
words = ['kinda','Scott']; //these are my keywords
var mapper = function() { //if searching for 'kinda', I want this function to emit (kinda, 1). This is not working
    emit( words[i], 1);          
};

var reducer = function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values) //this sums all of the ones and thereby gets the total # of docs that contain the keyword
};


for (var i=0; i<words.length;i++) { //here I'm iterating over the words array
result = db.messages.mapReduce(mapper,
                               reducer,
                               {
                                   out: { merge: 'keywordCollectiontest'}, //the results of each mapReduce are added to this collection
                                   query: {msg: {$regex: words[i]}} //this returns only the docs that contain words[i]
                               }
)
    printjson(result) //this simply shows information about how the mapReduce went
}
```

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
$ mongo fifthMapReduce.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.7
connecting to: test
Sun Nov 17 20:27:50.017 map reduce failed:{
"errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: words is not defined near 'emit( words[i], 1)'  (line 2)",
"code" : 16722,
"ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:970
failed to load: fifthMapReduce.js
```

So the exact error I'm getting is this:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError: words is not defined near 'emit( words[i], 1)'  (line 2)"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This part `var mapper = function()` is wrong for sure. You did not provide any argument for that function.

Comment: I want mapper to use the words array, so if I change mapper to say `function mapper(array) {
    emit( array[i], 1);
};` so then in my mapReduce I change the mapper part to `mapper(words)` I get an error saying that emit is not defined.

Comment: How is collection `messages` defined? Based on it you have to define your functions mapper and reducer. See [example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/)

Comment: `messages` is simply `{msg: 'here is a message'}` and I am searching for keywords inside the message strings using regex. The messages don't contain the keyword as a field value so that's why I need some way to pass the keyword into mapper.